# how to stop asp.net from uploading posted file

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a httpHandler, in my source code if some conditions aren't met i would like to stop uploading file to the server ( for example file extension is not allowed)

When I try to quit `ProcessRequest` function with `return null;`, asp.net tries and uploads the file automatically before I quit the httpHandler...

How can I stop asp.net to automatically upload posted files?

Here is the list of thing I've tested so far and no luck:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    var worker = (HttpWorkerRequest)provider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));
    ..........
    worker.CloseConnection();
    context.Response.End();
    Environment.Exit(0);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that IIS fully uploads the file to a working location before your application is handed the request.

[IIS asp.net mvc partial? file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722487/iis-asp-net-mvc-partial-file-upload)

If you truly want to control size and file type (extension) you will need to use an async upload process. I have had good luck with "uploadify".

http://www.uploadify.com/